# printing contents of a http file to a shell?

Tags: python, http, shell, tcsh

I want to be able to retrieve the contents of a log file stored on a server in the form of:

```
http://[SOME SORT OF ADDRESS]/file.txt
```

and print it to a shell which can refresh using something like 'watch' to keep a real time track of this log from a shell rather than having to use a broweser. Is there any neat and simple way of doing this (possibly later wrapped up into a python script).

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What do you mean by 'watch' and 'real time track'?

Comment: What do you mean by real time? Do you want to see streaming updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will fetch the requested url every every 0.1 seconds and display on console

```
watch -n 0.1  wget -qO- http://google.com
```

Comment: 0.1 might be too short a delay. Apart from that, looks sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `tail -f` works on Linux. However this will only work on local files. If the file is remote you will have to repeatedly fetch it to keep the updated (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

`watch "wget -N http://[SOME SORT OF ADDRESS]/file.txt &> /dev/null; cat file.txt"`

Comment: If you repeatedly `wget` the same file, each output will be saved under a new name (`file.txt.?`) so in your example you'll only ever see the first version. Have `wget` output to stdout instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
while sleep 60; do
    curl address
done
```

Will print out once a min

Adjust to your liking